# Crash in line where should be not crash in Swift ("if, let, where" statement)

Tags: ios, swift, crash, hockeyapp

I've been struggling with a very weird crash that should not happen at all. I receive the crash report via Hockeyapp, it keeps reporting a crash in a line that the app should not crash at all. I've been facing this problem for already 1 week.

This is the crash report

```
0   TeacherBox                           0x00000001000864f0 TeacherBox.RequestLessonViewController.loadExistingRequests () -> () (RequestLessonViewController.swift:755)
1   TeacherBox                           0x0000000100086514 @objc TeacherBox.RequestLessonViewController.loadExistingRequests () -> () (RequestLessonViewController.swift:0)
2   TeacherBox                           0x0000000100086a84 function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Dead> of TeacherBox.RequestLessonViewController.viewDidAppear (Swift.Bool) -> () (RequestLessonViewController.swift:122)
3   TeacherBox                           0x000000010007e570 @objc TeacherBox.RequestLessonViewController.viewDidAppear (Swift.Bool) -> () (RequestLessonViewController.swift:0)
4   UIKit                                0x00000001895b84dc -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 844
5   UIKit                                0x00000001895b8a40 -[UIViewController _endAppearanceTransition:] + 216
6   UIKit                                0x0000000189671038 -[UINavigationController navigationTransitionView:didEndTransition:fromView:toView:] + 1232
7   UIKit                                0x0000000189742198 __49-[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:]_block_invoke + 228
8   UIKit                                0x00000001896c7cc4 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 112
9   UIKit                                0x00000001898181ec __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke.97 + 708
10  UIKit                                0x00000001895d9214 -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 488
11  UIKit                                0x00000001895d8d38 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 308
12  UIKit                                0x00000001895d8b78 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 156
```

Lines of code:

```
if let booking = rescheduleBooking where booking.confirmed! == 0 {
    existingRequests.append(booking)
}
```

The line 755 is the if statement. In a "if, let, where" statement in swift, "let" checks for the existence of rescheduleBooking, if it exists and is assigned, the where statements is executed.... Am I right?... Anyway, I tested locally in my device and simulator and it doesn't crash there, no matter the values of the vars... it is happening in a different device that I don't have on hands..

Please, if you have any advice, or maybe, if I didn't understand correctly the "if, let where" clause, I will be very grateful of your help and comments.

Thanks..

Comment: remove `let` and try.

Comment: This will crash if `booking.confirmed` is nil because you have force unwrapped it

Answer (score 1):

Your Understanding of "if-let where" clause is correct, but you have to have in mind that `if let booking = rescheduleBooking` makes sure that `rescheduleBooking` is not `nil` and then assigns it to `booking`. Now even though `booking` is not `nil` that does not guarantee that `booking.confirmed` won't be `nil` so if it's `nil` and you force unwrap it it will cause a crash.

You can add another let to make sure `booking.confirmed` is not `nil`:

```
if let booking = rescheduleBooking, let bookingConfirmed = booking.confirmed where bookingConfirmed == 0 {
    existingRequests.append(booking)
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.. now confirmed is not an optional anymore, but it continue crashing there...

Comment: We should work our way up from the lowest line in the crash that is related to your code which is `3   TeacherBox                           0x000000010007e570 @objc TeacherBox.RequestLessonViewController.viewDidAppear (Swift.Bool) -> () (RequestLessonViewController.swift:0)
`. Can you please include the relevant code from that line?

Comment: And while you're at it if you can please include the complete crash report and relevant code for line number 2 and 1 from the crash report, so I can see what's going on to find out what's causing the crash.

Comment: You can also set break points to find out the exact line that is causing crash

Comment: All this crash is happening in the Smartphone of one of the testers, not in others... I decided to install XCode on his mac, connect that iPhone and see directly what is happening (via teamviewer cause' he is in a different country right now)... I will post here the solution... I really think the crash report from HockeyApp have some error, or at least is not pointing to the correct line..